# Adding comma separators to a number

Tags: filemaker

I'm working in Filemaker Pro 12. I want to display a field's number contents (`price`), rather than as simply a number, as comma separated. Ideally I want to do this while keeping the field contents a number, but displaying it with commas.

For example, the number `100000000` should display (in this layout) as `100,000,000`.

How can I do this?

*Older solutions on the internet seem to require Filemaker Advanced and custom scripts... **surely** it is possible without these?!*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the field in layout mode. In the Inspector palette, go to the Data tab and at the bottom, change the format to 'Decimal'. Check the box that says 'Use thousands separator.'